# Array within an array, within an object?

Tags: javascript

```
HeroName = new Hero()
HeroName.Spells = [];
HeroName.Spells[0].Type = [];
```

This doesnt work =( , even if I try new Array() or anything else. Is it not possible to do arrays within arrays? This is what I was going for:

```
HeroName.Spells[0].Type[0] = new DmgSpell();
HeroName.Spells[0].Type[1] = new Buff();
```

I know I can do something like

```
HeroName.Spells[0][0] = new DmgSpelL();
HeroName.Spells[0][1] = new Buff();
```

But this doesn't make it as easy to read

Am I doing something wrong? I've tried every possible combination I could think of and using google to search 'array within an array' gives me other results that don't help me. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `Spells[0]` needs to have an object assigned to it for that to work - at the moment it looks like you're trying to add a property `Type` to a nonexistant object.

Comment: Sorry for missing such an obvious thing and thank you so much for explaining it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed a step. You haven't declared `HeroName.Spells[0]` to be an object, so you can't a `Type` property to it, because it doesn't exist. This works:

```
HeroName = new Hero();
HeroName.Spells = [];
HeroName.Spells[0] = {};
HeroName.Spells[0].Type = [];
```

Comment: Doh I feel stupid now...thanks so much for your help, so glad it works out! thank you once again

Answer (score 3):

Set HeroName.Spells[0] as an Object, otherwise, it is `undefined`. `undefined` can't have any properties.

```
HeroName.Spells[0] = {};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain and write out an example